# Lookup table and dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm

In old games era, we are used to have a look-up table of pre-computed values of sin and cos,..etc, due to the slowness of computing those values in that old CPUs.

Is that considered a dynamic programming technique ? or dynamic programming must solve a recursive function that is always computed or sort of ?

Update: 
In dynamic programming the key is to have a memoization table, which is the solution for the sin,cos look up table, so what is really the difference in the technique ?

Comment: I'd say for what I see in your question no it's not dynamic programming. Dynamic programming is more about solving problems by solving smaller subproblem and create way to get solution of problem  from smaller subproblem.

Comment: I'd say it's more like lazy evaluation and not dynamic programming

Comment: Wikipedia has a description of dynamic programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Comment: @RomanPekar No, lazy evaluation is something completely different. This is just a space vs. time tradeoff, somewhat like memoization.

Comment: @Barmar my bad, memoization of course

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say for what I see in your question no it's not dynamic programming. [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is more about solving problems by solving smaller subproblem and create way to get solution of problem from smaller subproblem.

Your situation looks more like [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

For me it could be considered DP if your problem was to compute `cos N` and you have formula to calculate `cos i` from array of `cos 0`, `cos 1`, ..., `cos i - 1`, so you calculate `cos 1`, `sin 1` and run you calculation for i from 0 to N.

May be somebody will correct me :)

There's also interesting quote about how `dynamic programming` differ from `divide-and-conquer` paradigm:

> There are two key attributes that a problem must have in order for
>   dynamic programming to be applicable: optimal substructure and
>   overlapping subproblems. If a problem can be solved by combining
>   optimal solutions to non-overlapping subproblems, the strategy is
>   called "divide and conquer" instead. This is why mergesort and
>   quicksort are not classified as dynamic programming problems.

Answer (score 4):

Dynamic programming is the programming technique where you solve a difficult problem by splitting it in smaller problems, which are not independent (this is important!).

Even if you could compute cos i from cos i -1, this would still not be dynamic programming, just recursion.

Dynamic programming classic example is the knapsack problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

You want to fill a knapsack of size W, with N objects, each one with its size and value.
Since you don't know which permutation of objects will be the best, you "try" everyone.

Recurrence equation will be something like:

```
OPT(m,w) = MAX ( OPT(m-1, w), //if I don't take this object
                 OPT(m-1, w - w(m)) //If i take it
```

Adding the initial case, this is how you solve the problem. Of course you should build the solution starting with m = 0, w = 0 and iterating until m = N and w = W, so that you can reuse previously calculated values.

Using this technique, you can find the optimal combination of objects to bring into the knapsack in just N*W time (which is not polynomial in the input size, of course, otherwise P = NP and no one wants that!), instead of an exponential number of computation steps.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think this is dynamic programming. Due to limited computing power the values of sine and cosine were fed as pre-computed values which are just like other numeric constants.

For a problem to be solved in dynamic programming technique there are many essential conditions. One of the important condition is that we should be able to break problem into recursive solvable sub-problem, the result these sub-problem of which can be then used as look-up table to replace higher chain in recursion. So it is both recursion and memory.

For more info you can refer Wikipedia link.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Also the lecture 19 of this course will give you an overview of dynamic programming.
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-19-dynamic-programming-i-fibonacci-shortest-paths/